# Using cmd.exe in a VS Setup Custom Action

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, installation, custom-action

I set my Custom Action to cmd.exe and adding these arguments:

```
/K XmlPreProcess.exe /x:"[SETTINGSFILE]" /i:"[TARGETDIR]web.config" [CUSTOMSETTINGS] /e:[ENVIRONMENTBUTTON] >log.txt
```

I'm trying to either:

a) stop the command screen so I can read it

b) write the results to a file so I can read it.

[ENVIRONMENTUTTON] should be equal to QA - which I selected from a dialog form showing 4 radio buttons.  [SETTINGSFILE] is a user-entered field also a a dialog form.

The command window flashes by, I don't have time to read it, and no log.txt is created.

Original I was trying to run just XmlPreProcess.exe, but same problem, it was given an error and I couldn't see the error to debug it.

Related questions:
[Making sense out on .MSI verbose trace - running a CustomAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007635/making-sense-out-on-msi-verbose-trace-running-a-customaction)
[How to debug failure of a custom action in an MSI/Setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001747/how-to-debug-failure-of-a-custom-action-in-an-msi-setup-project)

Tried this once: msiexec /i "C:\MyPackage\Example.msi" /L*V "C:\log\example.log"
but didn't give much useful either - only confirmed that my values were substituting correctly in [SETTINGSFILE] and [ENVIRONMENTUTTON].

I'm posting as a new question because now I'm dealing specifically with cmd.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Which sequence is the custom action running in, and in what context?

Comment: I rewrote it in WIX.  Also modified the open-source XmlPreprocess program to log its parms to console and to a file on disk to help debug.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

- you want to use "/c" instead of "/k" ("/c" stops after executing the command)
- ">log.txt" writes the output next to the executed file, which is most likely in the Temp folder (custom actions are extracted there); you can try something like this:

  >"[DesktopFolder]log.txt"
- on newer Windows versions "C:\log\example.log" can be created only if you use an elevated command window

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but as I asked this question about 16 months ago, there is no way to validate it now... I'm at a different client.  (I saw a forum the other day where a question got answered after about 5 years!)

Comment: :) . Didn't notice that. For some reason it appeared as modified in my RSS reader.